# Resolved, Installation of CUDNN on ubuntu 18.04.3, need help

Tags: nvidia, cuda, tensorflow

Edit: I just installed from the tar file, but still from the deb file it does not work.

I hope I am on the good forum.
I'm trying to install Keras on my computer, but for this, I need to install tensorflow --> CUDNN, cuda, toolkit.

I follow the [nvidia documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/), I did the step 2.1.1. Installing NVIDIA Graphics Drivers, and the step 2.1.2. Installing The CUDA Toolkit For Linux. It seems for me that it was all good, but I can mislead myself.

Then at the step 2.3.2. Installing From A Debian File, I did what I was told to do,and I got this:

```
r@R:~/Téléchargements$ sudo dpkg -i libcudnn7_7.6.5.32-1+cuda10.2_amd64.deb
[sudo] password of r : 
(Reading the database... 208719 already installed files and directories.)
Preparation for unpacking libcudnn7_7.6.5.32-1+cuda10.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking of libcudnn7 (7.6.5.32-1+cuda10.2) of (7.6.5.32-1+cuda10.2) ...
Configuration of libcudnn7 (7.6.5.32-1+cuda10.2) ...
Processing of deferred actions (« triggers ») for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
```

Which seems weird for me. CUDNN seems not installed.
I then tried the check 2.4. Verifying The cuDNN Install On Linux:

```
r@R:~$ cp -r /usr/src/cudnn_samples_v7/ $HOME
r@R:~$ cd  $HOME/cudnn_samples_v7/mnistCUDNN
r@R:~/cudnn_samples_v7/mnistCUDNN$ make clean && make
rm -rf *o
rm -rf mnistCUDNN
Linking agains cublasLt = true
CUDA VERSION: 10020
TARGET ARCH: x86_64
HOST_ARCH: x86_64
TARGET OS: linux
SMS: 30 35 50 53 60 61 62 70 72 75
/usr/bin/ld : cannot find -lcudnn
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>>> WARNING - FreeImage is not set up correctly. Please ensure FreeImage is set up correctly. <<<
[@] /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -IFreeImage/include -m64 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_53,code=sm_53 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode arch=compute_62,code=sm_62 -gencode arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 -gencode arch=compute_72,code=sm_72 -gencode arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 -gencode arch=compute_75,code=compute_75 -o fp16_dev.o -c fp16_dev.cu
[@] g++ -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -IFreeImage/include -o fp16_emu.o -c fp16_emu.cpp
[@] g++ -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -IFreeImage/include -o mnistCUDNN.o -c mnistCUDNN.cpp
[@] /usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -m64 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_53,code=sm_53 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_61,code=sm_61 -gencode arch=compute_62,code=sm_62 -gencode arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 -gencode arch=compute_72,code=sm_72 -gencode arch=compute_75,code=sm_75 -gencode arch=compute_75,code=compute_75 -o mnistCUDNN fp16_dev.o fp16_emu.o mnistCUDNN.o -I/usr/local/cuda/include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -IFreeImage/include -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcublasLt -LFreeImage/lib/linux/x86_64 -LFreeImage/lib/linux -lcudart -lcublas -lcudnn -lfreeimage -lstdc++ -lm
r@R:~/cudnn_samples_v7/mnistCUDNN$ ./mnistCUDNN
bash: ./mnistCUDNN: No such file or folder
```

So, I think that the installation failed.

I tried to see why on the web.
in /usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64, I cannot find libcudnn.so nor liblcudnn.so

I got two path for cuda, and the first one seems to be empty...

```
r@R:~/Téléchargements$  whereis cuda
cuda: /usr/lib/cuda /usr/local/cuda
```

```
r@R:~/Téléchargements$ ldconfig -p | grep cudnn
libcudnn.so.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.7
r@R:~/Téléchargements$ sudo cp -P include/cudnn.h /usr/include
[sudo] password of r : 
cp: impossible to assess 'include/cudnn.h': No such file or folder
r@R:~/Téléchargements$ cat $(whereis cudnn.h) | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2
cat: 'cudnn:': No such file or folder
r@R:~/Téléchargements$ cat $(whereis cuda)/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2
cat: 'cuda:': No such file or folder
cat: /usr/lib/cuda: is a folder
cat: /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h: No such file or folder
```

I don't know what is wrong, but when I do an upgrate:

```
r@R:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building the dependency tree       
Reading status information... Done
You can do « apt --fix-broken install » to correct these problems.
The following packages contain unsatisfied dependencies :
 libcudnn7-doc : depends: libcudnn7-dev but it is not installable or
                          libcudnn7-dev-but it is not installable
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 9.1.85-3ubuntu1) but it is not installed
E:unsatisfied dependencies. Try « apt --fix-broken install » without package
   (or indicate a solution).
```

I don't know if libcudnn7-dev is the problem or CUDNN.
Can you help me please?

ps: I'm working without ubuntu 18.04.3 which is not in english, that's why I could have done some misstranslation.

Edit: after using the tar file I got:

```
r@R:~$ cat $(whereis cuda)/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2
cat: 'cuda:': No file or folder of this type
cat: /usr/lib/cuda: is a folder
#define CUDNN_MAJOR 7
#define CUDNN_MINOR 6
#define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 5
--
#define CUDNN_VERSION (CUDNN_MAJOR * 1000 + CUDNN_MINOR * 100 + CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL)
```

## include "driver_types.h"

So I think it's okay now.

Comment: I remember I was struggling while following the Nvidia documentation till I found [this link](https://gist.github.com/Mahedi-61/2a2f1579d4271717d421065168ce6a73#file-cuda_10-0_installation_on_ubuntu_18-04). It helped me more than the Nvidia documentation. If you encounter any problem, take a look at the comments in that link. And if you have Nividia driver 440.48.02, then you should install CUDA Version: 10.2

Comment: Hi singrium, thanks for helping. I just re-installed everything, everything was installed but I still had some problem, I didn't know where... So, I used this link [https://medium.com/@aspiring1/installing-cuda-toolkit-10-0-and-cudnn-for-deep-learning-with-tensorflow-gpu-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-f7e968b24c98] to install everything but I don't know if it's well installed x), I have some missing package... 'no such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-10.2/lib64
' .